# If Condition to check attribute's value

Tags: javascript

First of all, I am beginner in programming. I've got a question qbout JavaScript DOM. I would like to check if a tag or node has a backgroundColor style in order to execute the rest of the code, I also tried to put .clicked property but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
    let btn1 = document.getElementById("0");
    let btn2 = document.getElementById("1");
            
    btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        btn1.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        btn2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    });

    if (btn1.style.background == 'red' || span2.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
        console.log("test"); // doesn't work !!
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because your `if` statement only runs once. Wrap it inside a function and call that function after each click:

```js
let span1 = document.getElementById("0").getElementsByTagName("span")[1];
let span2 = document.getElementById("0").getElementsByTagName("span")[2];

span1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    span1.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    span2.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    checkColor();
});

span2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    span2.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    span1.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
    checkColor();
});

function checkColor() {
    if (
        span1.style.backgroundColor == "gray" ||
        span2.style.backgroundColor == "gray"
    ) {
        console.log("test"); // doesn't work !!
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="questions">
    <li id="0">
        <span>Do you like JavaScript?</span>
        <span>Yes</span><span>No</span><span class="result"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="1">
        <span>JavaScript and Java are the same</span>
        <span>Yes</span><span>No</span ><span class="result"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <span>JavaScript is easy to learn</span>
        <span>Yes</span><span>No</span><span class="result"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*Note: this snippet only includes the first 2 spans.*